# remove # from website URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, seo

suppose i have a single page website and the URL of a particular section is as follows
"www.website.com/#link", but for the SEO purposes "#" is not valid. So i want to ask that is there a way to remove this "#" from the URL and to get a URL like
"www.website.com/#link" with just the "#" removed.

Comment: First of all, tell us what adds that "#link". You need to fix that. Probably some menu link or something like that.

Comment: the # refers to an element with the id link.

Comment: ok, as i have mentioned it is a single page website, if i click on the "about" link in the menu it stays on the same page and scrolls down to the about section.

Comment: because the id of the section is "about" and the link on menu is <a href ="#about">

Comment: yes @KevinKloet exactly

Comment: Can you please post your script for the menu link click?

Comment: i think you can edit your robots.txt to ignore urls with # like this: User-agent: *
Disallow: /#

Comment: or if you want to have an url like www.website.com/link you can edit your .htaccess to load the content of the /#link.

Comment: @Samir there is no script, it is just a simple anchor link with # which jumps on to the id

Comment: @KevinKloet can you please help me with, what can be done with .htaccess file

Comment: i think the following is a valid htaccess rewrite rule: `RewriteRule ^link/?$    /#link   [L,NC]` if you want to know more about htaccess i recommend you to take a look at [this site](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html)

Comment: @KevinKloet i will suerly look into it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using the .htaccess file to reroute any URL from www.website.com/#link to www.website.com/link

You need something like this:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 # The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
 # exists, simply serve it.
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]


 RewriteRule .* #/$0
```

I am not a htaccess expert, so you might want to look into that forum.